# Ack find unquoted strings php 7.2 in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, regex, ack

Using ack, how can I find unquoted strings in arrays?.

I'm migrating to php 7.2, and this is the regex Im using:

```
ack -w --heading --php "\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*]"
```

Am I missing something, at glance seem ok.
However I don't know if I given false positives or false negatives missing some case.

Thanks

Comment: you are also finding `[]`, which you don't want. Replace `*` with `+`

Comment: Showing some sample inputs and expected outputs is helpful, indeed.

Comment: After taking a look at the `ack` documentation, it seems that the `-w` switch stands for *"-w, --word-regexp  -> Force PATTERN to match only whole words"*, since your pattern contains literal square brackets, I'm not sure it is able to return any result (depending of what *whole words* means). As previously said, your post suffer from a lack of sample.

Comment: Other thing, since you are looking for php unquoted associative array indexes (that may be constants or numeric indexes as an aside), that means that the code you are trying to update is very old, and in this case, you probably have to walk the hard way (reread and rewrite the code with your eyes and your fingers). Sorry for you.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use `ack --heading --php "\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]*]"` without `-w`.

---

As @CasimiretHippolyte mentioned in the comments `-w` requires the pattern to "match only whole words". The `-w` option simply wraps your search pattern in `\b` which requires spaces at the beginning and end of the match.

Remove the `-w` option and you should see the missing results.